# in Html table the word not wrapped in firefox alone

Tags: html, firefox

In html table,the text is automatically wrapped in IE and chrome. But Firefox it's taking more space and then wrapped.. What was the issue in firefox...Any idea..?. Please find the table below.. Column 1 has bigger text which wrapped and occupies less width in IE & chrome..The same occupies more width in firrefox

```
<table cellspacing="1" cellpadding="1" border="1">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th valign="top" align="center" colspan="5">
                    Header Col
                </th>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <th valign="top" align="center" cell="1" id="c0">
                    Col1
                </th>
                <th valign="top" align="center" cell="2" id="c1">
                    col2
                </th>
                <th valign="top" align="center" cell="3" id="c2">
                    col3
                </th>
                <th valign="top" align="center" cell="4" id="c3">
                    col4
                </th>
                <th valign="top" align="center" cell="5" id="c4">
                    col5
                </th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            <tr>
                <td valign="top" align="left" cell="1">
                    <table cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" border="0" class="deffont" style="width: 100%">
                        <tbody>
                            <tr>
                                <td width="15" valign="top" align="left" style="padding-bottom: 0px; margin: 0px;
                                    padding-left: 0px; padding-right: 0px; height: 100%; padding-top: 0px">
                                </td>
                                <td valign="top" align="left">
                                    <div>
                                        <div>
                                            <b><a></a><b>H-(D)p-ganeshgkdagkalyal-(D)seryl-(D)tryptophanyl-(D)seryl-(D)haninsdj-(D)cyclohexylalanyl-(D)arginyl-(D)arginyl-(D)arginyl-(D)glutaminyl-(D)arginyl-(D)arginine
                                                acetate salt</b><br>
                                                <br>
                                            </b>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                </td>
                            </tr>
                        </tbody>
                    </table>
                </td>
                <td valign="top" align="left" cell="2">
                    &nbsp;
                    <div>
                        <div>
                            <br>
                            <br>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </td>
                <td valign="top" align="left" cell="3">
                    <div>
                        <div>
                            For test in combination with test and test for the test of test with test.<br>
                            <br>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </td>
                <td valign="top" align="left" cell="4">
                    <div>
                        <div>
                            <table cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" border="0" class="deffont">
                                <tbody>
                                    <tr>
                                        <td>
                                        </td>
                                    </tr>
                                    <tr>
                                        <td>
                                            <b></b>
                                        </td>
                                    </tr>
                                    <tr>
                                        <td>
                                        </td>
                                    </tr>
                                    <tr>
                                        <td>
                                        </td>
                                    </tr>
                                </tbody>
                            </table>
                            <br>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </td>
                <td valign="top" align="left" cell="5">
                    <div>
                        <div>
                            DD: 12/22/11&nbsp;&nbsp;<br>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
```

Comment: Can you show us relevant CSS and html code ..

Comment: I have updated the question with code..please refer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add this style to your TD : `style="display: inline-block;word-break: break-all;"`

```
<table cellspacing="1" cellpadding="1" border="1">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th valign="top" align="center" colspan="5">
                    Header Col
                </th>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <th valign="top" align="center" cell="1" id="c0">
                    Col1
                </th>
                <th valign="top" align="center" cell="2" id="c1">
                    col2
                </th>
                <th valign="top" align="center" cell="3" id="c2">
                    col3
                </th>
                <th valign="top" align="center" cell="4" id="c3">
                    col4
                </th>
                <th valign="top" align="center" cell="5" id="c4">
                    col5
                </th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            <tr>
                <td valign="top" align="left" cell="1">
                    <table cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" border="0" class="deffont" style="width: 100%">
                        <tbody>
                            <tr>
                                <td width="15" valign="top" align="left" style="padding-bottom: 0px; margin: 0px;
                                    padding-left: 0px; padding-right: 0px; height: 100%; padding-top: 0px">
                                </td>
                                <td valign="top" align="left" style="display: inline-block;word-break: break-all;">
                                    <div>
                                        <div>
                                            <b><a></a><b>H-(D)p-ganeshgkdagkalyal-(D)seryl-(D)tryptophanyl-(D)seryl-(D)haninsdj-(D)cyclohexylalanyl-(D)arginyl-(D)arginyl-(D)arginyl-(D)glutaminyl-(D)arginyl-(D)arginine
                                                acetate salt</b><br>
                                                <br>
                                            </b>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                </td>
                            </tr>
                        </tbody>
                    </table>
                </td>
                <td valign="top" align="left" cell="2">
                    &nbsp;
                    <div>
                        <div>
                            <br>
                            <br>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </td>
                <td valign="top" align="left" cell="3">
                    <div>
                        <div>
                            For test in combination with test and test for the test of test with test.<br>
                            <br>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </td>
                <td valign="top" align="left" cell="4">
                    <div>
                        <div>
                            <table cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" border="0" class="deffont">
                                <tbody>
                                    <tr>
                                        <td>
                                        </td>
                                    </tr>
                                    <tr>
                                        <td>
                                            <b></b>
                                        </td>
                                    </tr>
                                    <tr>
                                        <td>
                                        </td>
                                    </tr>
                                    <tr>
                                        <td>
                                        </td>
                                    </tr>
                                </tbody>
                            </table>
                            <br>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </td>
                <td valign="top" align="left" cell="5">
                    <div>
                        <div>
                            DD: 12/22/11&nbsp;&nbsp;<br>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
```

Comment: It's working..But width is fully reduced...I need atleast to give meaningful width...Why it's taking more width in firefox..Any reason for that?

Comment: you can define the width attribute in style also... Rendering is browser dependent,Each Browser applies the css attribute according to their own implementation..hence browser compatibility issue arises..